# Inconsistency of behavior between Webflux's WebTestClient integration test and Postman REST call

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-test, project-reactor

I am struggling with a behavior **inconsistency** between an **integration test** and a **plain REST call**.

Let me explain: I had a bug in my production code causing a: `NoSuchElementException: Source was empty` exception when I perform a `POST` from a rest client (e.g. Postman).

I was trying to reuse a `Mono` that had already been subscribed to. See below:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createUser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    Mono<User> userMono = serverRequest.bodyToMono(User.class);//Can only be subscribed to once!!
    return validateUser(userMono)
        .switchIfEmpty(validateEmailNotExists(userMono))
        .switchIfEmpty(saveUser(userMono))
        .single();
}
```

However, the following integration test **has never been able to reproduce the production bug**!!

This is a green bar test:

```
@Test
void shouldSignUpUser() {
    WebTestClient client = WebTestClient
        .bindToRouterFunction(config.route(userHandler))
        .build();

    User user = User.builder()
        .firstName("John")
        .lastName("Smith")
        .email("john@example.com")
        .build();

    client
        .post()
        .uri("/api/user")
        .body(Mono.just(user), User.class)
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus()
        .is2xxSuccessful()
        .expectBody()
        .jsonPath("$.id")
        .isNotEmpty()
        .jsonPath("$.firstName")
        .isEqualTo("John");
}
```

Even if I specify a full web environment as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    properties = "spring.main.web-application-type=reactive",
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
```

I am not sure why my test passes when the POST call from Postman/curl fails. Can someone please advise? Where is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in how you're instantiating your `Mono`. In the "real" example, you're using `serverRequest.bodyToMono(User.class)` which will read the input stream and then parse the result into an object. When that input stream is consumed and closed, the data in it is gone - you can't just open it up again and get the same data out of it you did before. You therefore can't get a `User` object out of that same `Mono` unless you've cached its result.

`Mono.just()` however [explicitly uses a value that's "captured at instantiation time".](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#just-T-) That value, the user that you've build in that test, is essentially just a constant stored in that `Mono`, so it can be replayed indefinitely without issue.

As a simplified example, note the following:

```
public class DemoApplication {

    static class Foo {

        String bar;

        public String toString() {
            return bar;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.bar = "hello";
        Mono<Foo> mono = Mono.just(foo);

        mono.subscribe(System.out::println);
        mono.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

...which creates a new instance of `Foo` and uses `Mono.just`. We get "hello" printed twice, as expected.

However, your real-world use case is instead much more similar to the following:

```
public class DemoApplication {

    static class Foo {

        String bar;

        public String toString() {
            return bar;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("{\"bar\":\"hello\"}".getBytes());
        Mono<Foo> mono = Mono.fromSupplier(() -> new Gson().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(targetStream), Foo.class));

        mono.subscribe(System.out::println);
        mono.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

...which will only print "hello" once, since the first invocation always consumes the stream.

Comment: Thanks for that reply Michael. I understand your answer but is there not a way to mimic the "real" example in the test? I tried this: `.body(BodyInserters.fromObject(user))` instead of `.body(Mono.just(user), User.class)`. Still I cannot reproduce the bug from the test... What is more is it not worrying that a production bug cannot be spotted or reproduced by an integration test covering the very same execution path?

Comment: @balteo See the update, you'd have to mimic the `InputStream` behaviour to reproduce this behaviour in an "offline" test. The problem is that it's precisely *not* the same execution path, since the `Mono` isn't being created in the same way. If you want to implement that in your above example, you could create a utility method that takes a `User` object, serialises it to JSON, then creates an `InputStream` based on that JSON to use in `Mono.fromSupplier`. More verbose of course, but that means your test is much closer to your real example, so could catch cases like this.